# Java, Lucene : Sort search results with highest hit rate.

Tags: java, lucene

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am saving contents of user-data and using Lucene to index and search. Currently the functionality is working fine. **Is it possible to sort the result with the highest matching probability first?** I am currently saving paragraphs or more of text in indexes. Thank you.

Save code :

```
 Directory directory = org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(path);
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(new SimpleAnalyzer());
            IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
            indexWriter.commit();
            org.apache.lucene.document.Document doc = new org.apache.lucene.document.Document();
            if (filePath != null) {
                File file = new File(filePath); // current directory
                doc.add(new TextField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
            }
            doc.add(new StringField("id", String.valueOf(objectId), Field.Store.YES));
FieldType fieldType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
                fieldType.setTokenized(false);
                if(groupNotes!=null) {
                    doc.add(new Field("contents", text + "\n" + tagFileName+"\n"+String.valueOf(groupNotes.getNoteNumber()), fieldType));
                }else {
                    doc.add(new Field("contents", text + "\n" + tagFileName, fieldType));
                }
```

Search code :

```
File file = new File(path.toString());
                if ((file.isDirectory()) && (file.list().length > 0)) {
                    if(text.contains(" ")) {
                        String[] textArray = text.split(" ");
                        for(String str : textArray) {
                            Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
                            IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
                            IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
                            Query query = new WildcardQuery(new Term("contents","*"+str + "*"));
                            TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 100);

                            for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
                                System.out.println("Score is "+scoreDoc.score);
                                org.apache.lucene.document.Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                                objectIds.add(Integer.valueOf(document.get("id")));
                            }
                            indexSearcher.getIndexReader().close();
                            directory.close();
                        }
                    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The way you use lucene seems wrong, here you do not seem to tokenize your content and then you use a wildcard query (scores cannot be good). This is wrong, you should tokenize your data (with a TextField not a StringField). I strongly suggest following a tutorial to understand the basics. Also note that using lucene directly is extremely difficult, you should really consider using elasticsearch or solr.

Comment: @nomoa 
using lucene is difficult but it really dependy on your design and architecture decisions if you're able to use solr or elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a bit very clear to me so below are just guessed answers ,

1. There are methods in `IndexSearcher` which take `org.apache.lucene.search.Sort` as argument ,

   `public TopFieldDocs search(Query query, int n,
     Sort sort, boolean doDocScores, boolean doMaxScore) throws IOException` OR

   `public TopFieldDocs search(Query query, int n, Sort sort) throws IOException`

   See if these methods solve your issue.
2. If you simply want to sort on the basis of scores then don't collect only document Ids but collect score too in a pojo that has that score field .

   Collect all these pojos in some `List` then outside loop sort list on the basis 
   of score.

`for (ScoreDoc hit : hits) {
          //additional code
         pojo.setScore(hit.score);`

```
    list.add(pojo);

   }
```

then outside `for` loop ,

`list.sort((POJO p1, POJO p2) -> p2
            .getScore().compareTo(p1.getScore()));`